# PHP my admin doesnt work anymore after fatal error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

PHP my admin doesnt work anymore.. this is the error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 100 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\session.inc.php on line 96

I was running a query for 70.000 rows, but he was loading for a very long time. Now closed my browser and tried to start phpmyadmin again. But now I can't start phpmyadmin anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If phpmyadmin does not respond anymore, the query might still be running and blocking your connection. Try connecting via console, if possible*, and do the following:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

This will show you which process/es are still running, how long they have been running and most important, their id. If you see your monster query from before, kill it:

```
mysql> KILL QUERY 123;
```

*) if you don't have console access, you could also try to open phpMyAdmin from another browser and run the commands there.